# populate listbox with items selected under specific column headings

Tags: c#

I have populated a combobox with column headings in a csv file. Any ideas on how to populate listbox with data from each selected column heading in the combobox

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! Maybe you want a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
foreach (SelectedItem si in comboboxColumnHeadings)
{
    listBoxSelectedColumnHeadings.Add(si);
}
```

BTW, "column headings in a csv file" could be "values from a csv file"; it matters not whether they are column headings or moonshine recipe steps or anything else.